# How can I put result of a calculation with xsl in a new element

Tags: xml, xslt

I use a xsl to calculate the cumulative total per element "Basisproduct".
The output has finally to be put in the same xml, after "Totals" in some new elements, like this:

```
<Totals>
 <Totalproduct>
    <Basisproduct>110</Basisproduct>
    <Cumul_Amount>1,52</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
  </Totalproduct>
 <Totalproduct>
    <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
    <Cumul_Amount>294,77</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
  </Totalproduct>
 <Totalproduct>
    <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
    <Cumul_Amount>163,32</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
  </Totalproduct>
 <Totalproduct>
    <Basisproduct>993</Basisproduct>
    <Cumul_Amount>193,78</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
  </Totalproduct>
<Totals>

<-----I have this xml as an input.------>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report Name="SalesInvoice">
    <ReportName>SalesInvoice</ReportName>
  <Invoice>
    <InvoicingName>Test Company</InvoicingName>
  </Invoice>
  <ConditionalArea>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
        <Basisproduct>110</Basisproduct>
        <CustInvoice_LineAmount>1,52</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
        <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
        <CustInvoice_LineAmount>20,11</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
        <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
        <CustInvoice_LineAmount>20,22</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
        <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
        <CustInvoice_LineAmount>3033</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
        <Basisproduct>993</Basisproduct>
        <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30,34</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
        <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
        <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30,35</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
        <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
        <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.45</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
        <Basisproduct>993</Basisproduct>
        <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30,46</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
        <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
        <CustInvoice_LineAmount>100.99</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>,      </ConditionalArea>
  <Totals>
  </Totals>
</Report>
```

The xsl I use to calculate the cumlative sum of "Basisproduct" is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">              <xsl:output indent="yes"/>       <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:decimal-format name="EU" decimal-separator="," grouping-separator="."/>

<xsl:key name="KType" match="Basisproduct" use="."/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TotalSBasis">
     <TotalSBasis>
       <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*/Basisproduct [generate-id() = generate-id(key  ('KType', .)[1])]">
         <xsl:variable name="currProd" select="."/>
         <Totalproduct>
           <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
           <Cumul_Amount>
             <xsl:value-of select="sum(/*/*/BodyCustInvoiceTrans  [Basisproduct=$currProd]/CustInvoiceTrans_LineAmount)"/>
           </Cumul_Amount>
         </Totalproduct>
       </xsl:for-each>
           </TotalSBasis>
   </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Just for curiosity, what the sum is calulcating?  If you want to sum all `CustInvoice_LineAmount` with same `Baseproduct` I think you are totally wrong. Also your XSLT should be simplified.

Comment: In my answer I show you a simple XSLT which groups elements by `Basisproduct` and perform the sum of all the totals.

Comment: @empo - From the details in the last paragraph of the question, it sounds like the OP is getting the calculation results he/she was expecting, but wasn't sure how to output the results as an element structure and add it to the input XML. In my answer I left the OP's original calculation code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is use an identity transform and then just override the `Totals` element.

**EDIT: Based on a comment by the OP in @james.garriss answer, I modified the calculation to just sum everything.**

**Input XML**

```
<Report Name="SalesInvoice">
  <ReportName>SalesInvoice</ReportName>
  <Invoice>
    <InvoicingName>Test Company</InvoicingName>
  </Invoice>
  <ConditionalArea>
    <BodyCustInvoice>
      <Basisproduct>110</Basisproduct>
      <CustInvoice_LineAmount>1.52</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
    </BodyCustInvoice>
    <BodyCustInvoice>
      <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
      <CustInvoice_LineAmount>20.11</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
    </BodyCustInvoice>
    <BodyCustInvoice>
      <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
      <CustInvoice_LineAmount>20.22</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
    </BodyCustInvoice>
    <BodyCustInvoice>
      <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
      <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.33</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
    </BodyCustInvoice>
    <BodyCustInvoice>
      <Basisproduct>993</Basisproduct>
      <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.34</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
    </BodyCustInvoice>
    <BodyCustInvoice>
      <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
      <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.35</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
    </BodyCustInvoice>
    <BodyCustInvoice>
      <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
      <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.45</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
    </BodyCustInvoice>
    <BodyCustInvoice>
      <Basisproduct>993</Basisproduct>
      <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.46</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
    </BodyCustInvoice>
    <BodyCustInvoice>
      <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
      <CustInvoice_LineAmount>100.99</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
    </BodyCustInvoice>
  </ConditionalArea>
  <Totals> </Totals>
</Report>
```

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="KType" match="Basisproduct" use="."/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Totals">
    <Totals>
      <xsl:for-each select="/*/*/*/Basisproduct [generate-id() = generate-id(key  ('KType', .)[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="currProd" select="."/>
        <Totalproduct>
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
          <Cumul_Amount>
            <!--<xsl:value-of select= "/*/*/*[Basisproduct = current()][last()]/CustInvoice_LineAmount + sum(/*/*/*[Basisproduct = current()][last()]/preceding-sibling::*/CustInvoice_LineAmount)"/>-->
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(/*/*/BodyCustInvoice[Basisproduct=$currProd]/CustInvoice_LineAmount)"/>
          </Cumul_Amount>
        </Totalproduct>
      </xsl:for-each>      
    </Totals>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML** (Using Xalan :-( )

```
<Report Name="SalesInvoice">
   <ReportName>SalesInvoice</ReportName>
   <Invoice>
      <InvoicingName>Test Company</InvoicingName>
   </Invoice>
   <ConditionalArea>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>110</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>1.52</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>20.11</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>20.22</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.33</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>993</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.34</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.35</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.45</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>993</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.46</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>100.99</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
   </ConditionalArea>
   <Totals>
      <Totalproduct>
         <Basisproduct>110</Basisproduct>
         <Cumul_Amount>1.52</Cumul_Amount>
      </Totalproduct>
      <Totalproduct>
         <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
         <Cumul_Amount>141.32</Cumul_Amount>
      </Totalproduct>
      <Totalproduct>
         <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
         <Cumul_Amount>91.13</Cumul_Amount>
      </Totalproduct>
      <Totalproduct>
         <Basisproduct>993</Basisproduct>
         <Cumul_Amount>60.8</Cumul_Amount>
      </Totalproduct>
   </Totals>
</Report>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, the totals are OK now.

Comment: @ludo aerts - Excellent. If this answer was sufficient, please consider accepting it by clicking the check mark next to the answer. If not, please let me know what else isn't working as expected.

Comment: @DevNull, it seems OP wanted the calculation as I was thinking since the beginning ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<Totals>
  <xsl:for-each select="*/*/*/Basisproduct [generate-id() = generate-id(key  ('KType', .)[1])]">
    <Totalproduct>
      <Basisproduct><xsl:value-of select= "."/></Basisproduct>
      <Cumul_Amount>
        <xsl:value-of select= "/*/*/*[Basisproduct = current()][last()]/CustInvoice_LineAmount + sum(/*/*/*[Basisproduct = current()][last()]/preceding-sibling::*/CustInvoice_LineAmount)"/>
      </Cumul_Amount>
    </Totalproduct>
  </xsl:for-each>
</Totals>
```

This would output xml in the form mentioned, with the results you showed.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Updated my XSLT to accommodate OP's request to insert totals into the original XML.  The trick to solving the problem is to use the identity template and a global variable.

If you use this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="KType" match="Basisproduct" use="."/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- create a variable w/ the calculated totals -->
    <xsl:variable name="CalculatedTotals">
        <xsl:for-each select="*/*/*/Basisproduct [generate-id() = generate-id(key  ('KType', .)[1])]">
            <xsl:element name="TotalProduct">
                <xsl:element name="Basisproduct">
                    <xsl:value-of select= "."/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="Cumul_Amount">
                    <xsl:value-of select= "/*/*/*[Basisproduct = current()][last()]/CustInvoice_LineAmount + sum(/*/*/*[Basisproduct = current()][last()]/preceding-sibling::*/CustInvoice_LineAmount)"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- identity -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- root -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:template>    

    <xsl:template match="Totals">
        <xsl:copy>
            <!-- insert the calculated totals -->
            <xsl:copy-of select="$CalculatedTotals"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You will get this XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report Name="SalesInvoice">
   <ReportName>SalesInvoice</ReportName>
   <Invoice>
      <InvoicingName>Test Company</InvoicingName>
   </Invoice>
   <ConditionalArea>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>110</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>1.52</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>20.11</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>20.22</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.33</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>993</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.34</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.35</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.45</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>993</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.46</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>100.99</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
   </ConditionalArea>
   <Totals>
      <TotalProduct>
         <Basisproduct>110</Basisproduct>
         <Cumul_Amount>1.52</Cumul_Amount>
      </TotalProduct>
      <TotalProduct>
         <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
         <Cumul_Amount>294.77</Cumul_Amount>
      </TotalProduct>
      <TotalProduct>
         <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
         <Cumul_Amount>163.32</Cumul_Amount>
      </TotalProduct>
      <TotalProduct>
         <Basisproduct>993</Basisproduct>
         <Cumul_Amount>193.78000000000003</Cumul_Amount>
      </TotalProduct>
   </Totals>
</Report>
```

Tested with Oxygen 12 on Win 7.

Comment: Just so you're aware, `xsl:element` (or `xsl:attribute`) isn't necessary 99% of the time. This is one of those times.

Comment: Hi again, Is it possible to add the result under the input xml?

Comment: Certainly.  Did you look at the solution offered by @DevNull?  I think that's exactly what he did.

Comment: I saw the solution, and did a test. Looks great, the resultis OK as I wanted. But somwhere in the calculation there is a mistake, the resulting values are wrong.

Comment: @ludo aerts - what is the calculation you're trying to perform? are you just trying to sum everything?

Comment: @ludo aerts - please see my updated answer. james.garriss - thanks for pointing out my solution.

Comment: It is the Total per "Basisproduct". Sum of every "CustInvoice_LineAmount" for each "Basisproduct".

Comment: You bet, @DevNull.  I honestly missed that detail first time around; since you didn't, I figured you at least deserved a shot at the winning answer.

Comment: Hi, forgot that my original dat is in european number format. Sometimes values are 1,23 or 1.234,56 , forgot about that... How can the format be altered before the calculation?

Comment: I modified the number format in the example above to the one we use in Europe: 1.234,56   Until now I tried this in my xsl:

Comment: @ludo - Two choices:  <xsl:decimal-format...> or the format-number() function.  See this page for examples:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256225.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

This transform groups elements by `Basisproduct` and calculates the total sum of each group. Note that it includes by `identity.xsl` the well known [**Identity Transformation**](https://raw.github.com/gist/972175/b189899bb7701dde95a3cba04ced83356e738968/identity.xsl).

---

[XSLT 1.0]

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:include href="identity.xsl"/>

    <xsl:key name="KType" match="BodyCustInvoice" use="Basisproduct"/>

    <xsl:template match="Totals">
        <Totals>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="
                preceding-sibling::ConditionalArea[1]/BodyCustInvoice
                [generate-id() 
                = generate-id(key  ('KType', Basisproduct)[1])]" mode="totals"/>
        </Totals>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="BodyCustInvoice" mode="totals">
        <Totalproduct>
            <Basisproduct><xsl:value-of select="Basisproduct"/></Basisproduct>
            <Cumul_Amount>  
                <xsl:value-of select="
                    sum(key('KType',Basisproduct)/CustInvoice_LineAmount)"/>
            </Cumul_Amount>
        </Totalproduct>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output:

```
<Report Name="SalesInvoice">
   <ReportName>SalesInvoice</ReportName>
   <Invoice>
      <InvoicingName>Test Company</InvoicingName>
   </Invoice>
   <ConditionalArea>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>110</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>1.52</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>20.11</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>20.22</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.33</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>993</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.34</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.35</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.45</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>993</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>30.46</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
      <BodyCustInvoice>
         <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
         <CustInvoice_LineAmount>100.99</CustInvoice_LineAmount>
      </BodyCustInvoice>
   </ConditionalArea>
   <Totals>
      <Totalproduct>
         <Basisproduct>110</Basisproduct>
         <Cumul_Amount>1.52</Cumul_Amount>
      </Totalproduct>
      <Totalproduct>
         <Basisproduct>198</Basisproduct>
         <Cumul_Amount>141.32</Cumul_Amount>
      </Totalproduct>
      <Totalproduct>
         <Basisproduct>992</Basisproduct>
         <Cumul_Amount>91.13</Cumul_Amount>
      </Totalproduct>
      <Totalproduct>
         <Basisproduct>993</Basisproduct>
         <Cumul_Amount>60.8</Cumul_Amount>
      </Totalproduct>
   </Totals>
</Report>
```

Comment: I can't get your stylesheet to output the "Totals". Maybe because the select in your apply-templates is looking for "ConditionalArea" as a child of "Totals"?

Comment: @DevNull thanks your feedback is correct. I just edited the transform on the fly today without testing (:too much confident:). Now I fixed it so that totals are displayed. Thanks.